# Manually setting routing points for an edge (mxGraph)

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

How might I go about setting my own points for where the edge will bend?

I am in need of the ability to do this because of the following picture:

[image]

Where you can see three different edges all running together. I want to be able to add an offset to where the edges initially bend so each edge will be visible.

I cannot get parallel edges to work at all, so I feel my only option is to somehow do something to make it so each of these edges goes out right from the vertex some random amount before bending up.

All I have found is setting `routingCenterX` to my edge style, which, to no surprise, does absolutely nothing. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try cell.geometry.points = [new mxPoint(x, y)];